# Trying to access the retrieve method from deployed smart contract but not able to using ether.js

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, javascript

[image]

Above is the the error I'm getting when trying to access the retrieve method from the smart contract I've written although I'm able to get the contract object which means I've connected to the contract successfully

I've also attached my solidity contract here as well below also attached my js code
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like you forget to provide the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct ABI , find the `retrieve` function in the ABI . Also check your `ethers` version and check the docs for that version , how are they calling the contract. Also try to hit the contract from block explorer if verified otherwise use remix.